# Particle statistics in fractal dimensions?

Tags: group-theory, spin-statistics, fractals

We know that *fermions* and *bosons* are the only two (indistinguishable) particle statistics for $d\geq 3$, and that *anyons* are for $d=2.$

What if the space were a fractal? Like the Sierpinski gasket, with $d=1.585$?

**EDIT for clarity, to try and keep the question open:**

[Here](https://phys.org/news/2018-11-physicists-fractal-electrons.html) they have electrons in a Sierpinski gasket shaped potential. 
 The Sierpinski gasket has a fractal dimension. 
 If I want to permute the positions of indistinguishable particles, I have to do this in this fractal dimension. So this neither $SO(2)$ ($d=2$) not $SO(1)$. 
 The first homotopy (fundamental) group of such group, $\pi_1(SO(d))$ would give the number of distinct statistics: $\mathbb{Z}$ in $d=2$ (anyons) and $\mathbb{Z_2}$ in $d\geq3$ (fermions, bosons).

How would I go on about it here, in $d = 1.58$?

Comment: I think the main confusion I have is that [fractal dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal_dimension) are not dimensions, but a measure of the complexity of the shape/curve.